# Copy and Paste not working in VM console

Tags: virtualbox, copy, paste

I am really trying to install some software in my VirtualBox VM by pasting a link address from Google Chrome browser and there is no such paste in my console. Installed guest additions, I enabled clipboard features such (bidirectional) and for drag and drop, but it is not really working.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! I’d check whether the Guest Additions are actually running. The way to check it depends on the OS… What is your host and guest OS?